# Widget images showing iOS 15 problem. Black rectangle appears/disappear on images

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios15

After updating to a new version of the operating system(iOS 15), the widget in the application I am working on began to work incorrectly. Some pictures in the widget are covered with black squares or rectangles that can disappear or appear in the process of interacting with the widget.

Maybe this is some kind of text recognition mechanism in pictures from Apple? Has anyone come across a similar one?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you test on simulator or device?

Comment: @AntonBelousov device.

Comment: I'm experiencing same behavior as well. Images are downloaded (and cached) remotely from https. The absurd thing is that if i click any of my items (thus opening the app) and I get back to the home screen, images are working properly